# Can I use a Regular Expression within jQuery.inArray()

Tags: jquery, regex

I would like the following `if` statement to alert 'yes' if 'featured' is in array, regardless of whether it is uppercase or lowercase.

I'm also not very familiar with Regular Expressions, so perhaps my regular expression is wrong..

```
var myArray = ["featured", "foo", "bar"];

if( $.inArray(/featured/i, myArray) > -1 ){
    alert('yes!');
}
```

Also, [here is a jsfiddle of the above](http://jsfiddle.net/benrosati/85s9G/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `$.inArray` supports regular expressions, but you could make your own function that does.

```
$.inArrayRegEx = function(regex, array, start) {
    if (!array) return -1;
    start = start || 0;
    for (var i = start; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (regex.test(array[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/H4Y9A/

---

You could even override the existing inArray to make it "optionally" support regular expressions while still retaining its regular functionality:

```
(function() {
    var originalInArray = $.inArray;
    $.inArray = function(regex, array, start) {
        if (!array) return -1;
        start = start || 0;
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(regex) === "[object RegExp]") {
            for (var i = start; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (regex.test(array[i])) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        } else {
            return originalInArray.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
})();
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3sK7U/

Note: the one thing you would lose with this override is the ability to find a regular expression object itself in an array.

Comment: Added an override of the existing $.inArray that would add support for regular expressions.  Also, added support for the optional 3rd parameter to `$.inArray()`.

Answer (score 3):

An array is not a string, but you can make it a string, by using [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

```
if(/featured/.test(myArray.toString())){
    alert('yes!');
}
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uAzt2/)

Comment: This wont work, you cant check for commas this way (as .toString adds some)

Comment: Yes it does add commas, but he doesn't care for commas. If you check the fiddle, you will see that it does work.

Comment: It does work for that particular example, but we don't know how far OP is going with this. Also this might be counterproductive for people who come here in search for a solution for their own problem.

Comment: Well, the scope of the question doesn't address how far he is going with this. We can be responsible for all edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so.

This is how I would to it, using (`$.each` and `match()`):

```
var myArray = ["featured", "foo", "bar"];


$.each(myArray,function(index,value){
    if(value.match(/featured/i) !== null){
        alert("Yes!");
        return false;
    }
});
```

on JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/QGtZU/

Comment: That may cause multiple alerts, op wants to check if there is a case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$.grep](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) to filter the array and then check the length:

```
 if ( $.grep( myArray, function (e, i ){ return /featured/i.test(e); }).length > 0 )
    alert( "YES!" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Version using Javascript [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and forEach. It achieves the same but does not use inArray.

```
var myArray = ["featured", "foo", "bar"];

var exp = /featured/i;

myArray.forEach( function(value){

   if( exp.exec(value) ){
    alert("yes");
   }

} );
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9J4g5/)**