# Check does an array contains input text on keyUp

Tags: javascript, regex

I searched about this and all I found is that all answers contains `indexof`, which for some reason does not work in my option:

I have an array:

```
var array = ["Sunny","Snowy","Rainy"];
var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
```

Now When I use indexOf it works only when I input the whole word, I need it in way:

```
Input: S
Result: Sunny, Snowy
Input: Su
Result: Sunny
```

Here is the code:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (input.indexOf(array[i])> -1) {
                console.log("Object with index number "+i+" contains "+input); 
            }
            return;
    }
```

Just plain javascript without jquery.

Comment: i think this link is what you want :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447021/can-i-use-a-regular-expression-within-jquery-inarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `indexOf()` operands backwards. `input` is also a DOM element, and you are asking if the DOM element contains the array element, rather than asking if the DOM element's **value** is in the array. Here's how you can modify it to work:

```js
var array = ["Sunny", "Snowy", "Rainy"];
var input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].indexOf(this.value) > -1) {
      console.log("Object with index number " + i + " contains " + this.value);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
```

**EDIT** -- As per OP's request to use inline keyup event handler and not return any results if input value is empty -- *Note: using the keyup event is not advised because it does not capture mouse cut & paste, and unnecessarily fires on modifier keys (shift, ctrl, alt, etc). The `input` event is more useful here.*

```js
var array = ["Sunny", "Snowy", "Rainy"];
var input = document.getElementById('input');

function handleKeyup(elem) {
  // return nothing if empty value in input
  if (elem.value !== "") {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i].indexOf(elem.value) > -1) {
        console.log("Object with index number " + i + " contains " + elem.value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" onkeyup="handleKeyup(this)" />
```

Comment: @pooyan `Array.prototype.indexOf()` is different than `String.prototype.indexOf()`

Comment: Otherwise this is not working While i type in input it is not doing a thing and after I delete it all I get Object with index number 0 contains

Comment: @BestBudds Added working demo with same code. Can you try to explain what is not working for you? Or do you want it to return no results if the input field is empty? Technically, every element contains `""`, so if you empty the field, it will return all results. This is the desired behavior in 99% of cases, but if you don't want it to work like that, just let me know and I can update my code

Comment: I tried to call function onkeyup="functionName()" on input and then do this for...

Comment: @mhodges i think it would be better that at first check that your input is not empty.

Comment: @BestBudds Updated answer. Try the bottom example if you are wanting inline event handlers. I will mention, though, that using keyup is not a great option, as it does not handle mouse cut & paste, and any time you hit a modifier key (shift, alt, ctrl, etc.) it will also run your function unnecessarily. Binding an event listener to the `input` event as I did in my first example is much more preferable.